# Null parameters in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What is the best method of handling null parameters in stored procedure ?

I have a stored procedure with 3 input parameters, any one of them parameter can be null so how to handle those parameter.

`SP_GetDetails` input parameter (`varchar p1, varchar p2, int p3, datetime p4, datetime p5`)

In the stored procedure, there are different query based on input parameters.

```
if(p1<>null)
///
else
 if(p2<>null)
 ///
 else
  if()... so on...
```

So my question: Is it good to have n number of if condition.

Comment: Please provide an example. The information in this question is insufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing a lot of detail. I suspect this might be of help though. [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)

Answer (score 0):

The using of multiple `If` statements in stored procs detract from the readability of the code. Also, the maintainability of the code suffers. Instead you can use `CASE` statements.